# jquery post request to rails server to receive json data returns 404 error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cordova

I am trying to have a phonegap app communicate with the rails app in the back end. Currently, I am trying to get the login to work. I have the following jquery code that runs once submit button is clicked

```
$("#new_user").click(function(){
    var hash     = {"user":{"email":$("#user_email").val(),"password":$("#user_password").val()}};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_in/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: hash,
        success: function() { alert("Success"); },
        error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
    });
});
```

The following curl request works in the terminal 
`curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d ' {"user":{"email":"dummy@gmail.com","password":"password"}}'  http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_in`

In order to test the jquery code, I have a rails server locally running on my computer. But every time I click the button and have the code send the POST request.I get a 404 error. Is it because I am running it in my local machine?

Comment: Just send in a simple dictionary. Not a nested one.

Comment: The server side expects a nested hash

Answer (score 0):

try using localhost instead of 0.0.0.0

Comment: my next guess is remove the "/" at the end in `url: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_in/',` so that it is `..../users/sign_in` and may be remove the `crossDomain: true` since you are posting to the same domain.